# Why does unit test for Razor Page handler return type of PartialViewResult fail?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, xunit

I am using Core 3.1 Xunit to test a Razor Page in an application, with Moq to mock any services. When running a test on a handler of `PageModel` to test if it returns `PartialViewResult` type I get the following exception:

```
System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The `PageModel` handler looks like this, with `Application` as a property on `PageModel`:

```
public PartialViewResult OnGetApplicationAddedModalPartial()
{
    return Partial("_ApplicationAddedModalPartial", Application);
}
```

And this is the failing test for it:

```
[Fact]
public void OnGetApplicationAddedModalPartial_WhenCalled_ShouldReturPartialViewResultType()
{
    //Arrange
    _sut.Application = It.IsAny<ApplicationModel>();

    //Act
    var result = _sut.OnGetApplicationAddedModalPartial();

    //Assert
    Assert.IsType<PartialViewResult>(result);
}
```

What's curious is that I have another handler in that `PageModel` that I successfully test to see if the return is of `JasonResult` type. Additionally, I have controllers in this application of which some actions also return a `PartialViewResult` type that I successfully test for.

What is special about a handler of return type `PartialViewResult` on a `PageModel` and how can I create a test to ensure that it returns `PartialViewResult`?

Comment: There is a threat that this question can be closed as duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) ;)

Answer (score 0):

When testing a `PartialViewResult`, you need to instantiate a number of properties of the `PageModel` as part of your setup: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/24312

```
// Arrange
var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
var modelState = new ModelStateDictionary();
var actionContext = new ActionContext(httpContext, new RouteData(), new PageActionDescriptor(), modelState);
var modelMetadataProvider = new EmptyModelMetadataProvider();
var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(modelMetadataProvider, modelState);
var tempData = new TempDataDictionary(httpContext, Mock.Of<ITempDataProvider>());
var pageContext = new PageContext(actionContext)
{
    ViewData = viewData
};
var pageModel = new MyPageModel()
{
    PageContext = pageContext,
    TempData = tempData,
    Url = new UrlHelper(actionContext),
    MetadataProvider = modelMetadataProvider
};

// Act    
var result = await pageModel.GetPartial();

// Assert
Assert.IsType<PartialViewResult>(result);
```